# Scheduling Logic for Calendar Events That Repeat on a Monthly Basis

Tags: date, calendar, logic, scheduling

I'm currently developing a internal application for a company that does patient transport between hospitals and doctor's offices.  The module that I'm working on now will give the company the ability to track their various vehicle maintenance expenses and services performed  as well as give them the ability to schedule different maintenance services for each vehicle in their fleet.

Different types of maintenance are performed at different time intervals.  These are to be repeating events.  Some are to be repeated weekly, some monthly, and others every three months.

For the maintenance events that repeat on a monthly or semi-monthly basis I'm a little unsure how I should go about determining days in future months that a event should be scheduled if the date is late in the month and that particular day does not exist a in a subsequent month.

For example, if I schedule a event on January 31st that is to be repeated monthly then I'm unsure where in February that event should be assigned.  I would appreciate any suggestions from anyone who has developed a scheduling application detailing how you accounted for these  types of scheduling problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I jumped the gun asking this question.  I decided to see how Google Calendar handles monthly recurring events.  If I add a event for January 31st 2012 and set it as a recurring event then I am given the option to have that event repeat every month that has day 31 or to repeat the last Tuesday of each month.

In my case it would be best to have the event repeat the last Tuesday of each month because the vehicle maintenance shop is closed on Sundays and the maintenance cannot skip a month just because that particular day did not exist in each month.